# How to pass value when click on submit button?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having a problem when passing value to url while creating, updating article in rails. I have tried:

```
<%= f.button 'submit', {:action=>'show', :id_dru=>"3"} %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to append those to the ***form***, not ***submit button***.

```
<%= form_for @model_intance, url: {:action=>'show'}, html: {:id_dru=>"3"} %>
```